# Why is my solution for the powerset question incorrect? I have included my recursive and iterative approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

Question is basically to generate all subsets given an array of unique integers.

For example `powerSet[1,2,3]` should return `[[], [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]`

Here is my recursive attempt:

```
function powerset(array) {
  // Write your code here.
    let set = [[]];
    powersetHelper(array, [], set);
    return set;
}

function powersetHelper(array, subset, set) {
    if (array.length === 0) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        subset.push(array[i]);
        set.push(subset);
    }
    let newArr = array.slice(1);
    powersetHelper(newArr, [], set)
}
```

**Why is this returning `[[], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3]]` instead of the correct solution?**

Additionally, I have attempted this iteratively as follows:

```
function powerset(array) {
  // Write your code here.
    let subset = [];
    let set = [[]];
    while (array.length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            let num = array[j];
            subset.push(num);
            set.push(subset);
        }
        array = array.slice(1);
    }
    return set;
}
```

This is also incorrect and somehow returning what I have below even though it seems to be the same logic as my recursive solution

```
[
  [],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a copy without object reference.

```js
function powerSet(array) {
    // Write your code here.
    let set = [[]];
    powersetHelper(array, [], set);
    return set;
}

function powersetHelper(array, subset, set) {
    if (array.length === 0) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        subset.push(array[i]);
        set.push([...subset]); // take copy without object reference
    }
    let newArr = array.slice(1);
    powersetHelper(newArr, [], set)
}

console.log(powerSet([1, 2, 3])); // [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Second one, with the same problem

```js
function powerSet(array) {
    // Write your code here.
    let subset = [];
    let set = [[]];
    while (array.length > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            let num = array[j];
            subset.push(num);
            set.push([...subset]);
        }
        array = array.slice(1);
    }
    return set;
}

console.log(powerSet([1, 2, 3])); // [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Both outputs are still wrong :)

Comment: I figured it out using this same logic. You are right, I was pushing a reference to subset into the set which does not work. I have to push that actual subset in that moment of time, and not allow it to be changed. I have included my working solution in an edit above which is very similar to yours (I just slice it to make a copy instead of spread operator)

Comment: Actually, this solution is still wrong because it does not actually get the [1,3] case